# Filling an array but get value 'null' in Google Apps Script

Tags: arrays, variables, google-apps-script

am confused. I have an array of 'keys' where each key has a number. I have an array of my current row of data.

Now I need to fill a new array, where we match the key and value like this:

```
var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('box');   //MAAK FORMULIER KLAAR, HIER ALLE VARIABELEN DIE UIT DE RECORD KOMEN

template.action = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
template.ID=data[keys.key_ID];
template.AccountManager=data[keys.key_AccountManager];
template.Status=data[keys.key_Status];
template.Terugbeldatum=data[keys.key_Terugbeldatum];
template.Schoolnaam=data[keys.key_Schoolnaam];
template.Bezoekadres=data[keys.key_Bezoekadres];
template.Huisnr=data[keys.key_Huisnr];
template.Postcode=data[keys.key_Postcode];
template.Plaats=data[keys.key_Plaats];
template.Telefoon=data[keys.key_Telefoon];
template.Website=data[keys.key_Website];
template.Voorletters=data[keys.key_Voorletters];
template.Voornaam=data[keys.key_Voornaam];
template.VVAS=data[keys.key_VVAS];
template.Achternaam=data[keys.key_Achternaam];
template.Functie=data[keys.key_Functie];
template.Vakantieregio=data[keys.key_Vakantieregio];
template.LAS=data[keys.key_LAS];
template.LASDatum=data[keys.key_LASDatum];
template.ZelfstandigeInkoop=data[keys.key_ZelfstandigeInkoop];
template.Gespreksverslag=data[keys.key_Gespreksverslag];
template.SeminarDatum=data[keys.key_SeminarDatum];
template.AfspraakDatum=data[keys.key_AfspraakDatum];
template.Statushistorie=data[keys.key_Statushistorie];
template.Gesprokenmet=data[keys.key_Gesprokenmet];
template.Verantwoordelijke=data[keys.key_Verantwoordelijke];
template.TelefoonnummerV=data[keys.key_TelefoonnummerV];
template.row=row;
template.Emailadres=data[keys.key_Emailadres];
template.EmailadresV=data[keys.key_EmailadresV];
template.welkom = false;
```

Result:

http://imm.io/UP5b

Just a few variables get it into the template array, the rest is 'null' ???

When I do a

```
 Logger.log(data[keys.key_Exxx]);
```

the value is there just fine.

Cannot I assign so many variables into Template this way?

Comment: Looks like there is something wrong using Copy-Paste, 

template.TelefoonnummerV=data[keys.key_TelefoonnummerV];

It seems like there is an extra character after the _  ???

I have been using a regex-tool to replace some text. Strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is something wrong using Copy-Paste, template.TelefoonnummerV=data[keys.key_TelefoonnummerV]; It seems like there is an extra character after the _ ??? I have been using a regex-tool to replace some text. Strange. – Riel yesterday